# Two sum sub-queries in one select query getting error

Tags: c#, sql, database, join, subquery

I have 3 tables

1. Orders
2. Order_customer (bridge table)
3. Customer

- I have orderid, quantity, timing(morning, evening), orderDate  in orders
- orderid and customerid in Order_customer
  And
- customer name in customer

I'm making a join for data collection after a sum group by query and making it a sub query to collect the data like

`Customername | Morning (qty) | Evening (qty)`

The morning data output is good but its adding evening values of every customer

[image one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yM7S.jpg)
[image two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJP0e.jpg)

I'm using below query for data collection and image one is sum result of both together and two is evening actual results can anyone help ??

then i also want date wise sorting in them

```
select 
  c.customername, 
  SUM(productQuantity) Morning, 
  (
    select 
      SUM(productQuantity) evening 
    from 
      Orders o 
      INNER JOIN Order_Customer t ON o.orderId = t.orderId 
      LEFT JOIN customer C ON T.customerId = C.customerid 
    where 
      o.timing = 'Evening'
  ) evening 
from 
  Orders o 
  INNER JOIN Order_Customer t ON o.orderId = t.orderId 
  LEFT JOIN customer C ON T.customerId = C.customerid 
where 
  o.timing = 'Morning' 
  and o.orderDate = '2/23/2023' 
GROUP BY 
  c.customername
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your evening clause is not part of customername group by. That's what went wrong.

To get what you want, you can first build group by in (customername, timing) condition, and then have a full outer join on morning and evening records.

See the following code as an example:

```
with customer_timing_quantity AS 
(select 
  c.customername, 
  o.timing,
  SUM(productQuantity) as quantity 
from 
  Orders o 
  INNER JOIN Order_Customer t ON o.orderId = t.orderId 
  LEFT JOIN customer C ON T.customerId = C.customerid 
where 
  o.orderDate = '2/23/2023' 
GROUP BY 
  c.customername,
  o.timing
)
SELECT
    COALESCE(m.customername, e.customername) as customername,
    COALESCE(m.morning,0) as morningquantity,
    COALESCE(e.evening,0) as eveningquantity,
    COALESCE(m.morning,0) + COALESCE(e.evening,0) as totalquantity
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        customername,
        quantity as morning
    FROM
        customer_timing_quantity
    WHERE
        timing = 'Morning'
    ) m
FULL OUTER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
        customername,
        quantity as evening
    FROM
        customer_timing_quantity
    WHERE
        timing = 'Evening'
) e
ON
  m.customername = e.customername
```

[VERIFIED RUNNING EXAMPLE SQLFIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/572f99/7)

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
Incorrect syntax near '='.     having this error near FULL OUTER JOIN, and thankyou for this help.

Comment: HI @MuhammadHassanSiddiqui, found the issue and I have correted the code and also update with a verified running example in sqlfiddle link.  You can havve another try.

Comment: thankyou so much @junjie for this help i Appreciate you and this platform which helps me.

Comment: hey can i add another column in it for the total quantity ?? maybe i will try it with programming by the way thans alot

Comment: Hi @MuhammadHassanSiddiqui, could you clarify what total quantity mean here? You mean total_quantity = morning_quantity + evening_quantity?

Comment: yes exactly its morning + evening

Comment: hay thankyou for your help i have done this programatically thankyou for all the support thaks alot

Comment: Hi @MuhammadHassanSiddiqui, you can use coalesce() function to do that. I have updated the query to also calculate totalquantity

Comment: Thnakyou @junji for this much help. its great now.

Comment: Brother, i need some more changes in this query i can tell you, i want the average of total in a new column can you help me eg. Totalquantity/(count(entries)/2) like this